# What is this exception: Cipher buffering error in JCE provider JsafeJCE

Tags: java, ssl, coldfusion

We are getting this error when trying to change a password in ColdFusion through LDAP.

Despite the error, everything seems to be completing as requested.

The stack trace ends at the start of a thread so I can't tell the exact trigger point.

**EDIT:**

We started getting these errors when we moved from CFMX7 to ColdFusion 9.

Here is the stack trace.

> Exception in thread "Thread-5244" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cipher buffering error in JCE provider JsafeJCE
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.encrypt(CipherBox.java:144)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.encrypt(OutputRecord.java:197)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:733)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:722)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.sendAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1720)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1606)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1574)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1538)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1483)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:86)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
>     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:767)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [forum thread on adobe.com](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/507614) seems to offer a solution to this problem.

Key quote, by one user named "wizzi_vt":

> `-Dcoldfusion.disablejsafe=true` in your `jvm.config` will prevent these
>   errors. I believe it will also remove
>   the Bsafe encryption methods from the
>   encrypt function documented as having
>   been added in CF8.